# JibGrid - Silverlight DataGrid With Paging, Grouping, Freezing, and Filtering

Tags: silverlight, wcf, mvvm, datagrid

I am using JibGrid to filtering data offline, so you can download the grid from this line:

http://jibgrid.codeplex.com/

my problem is:

I Can't Filtering Columns from another tables in Grid Like Department Column in this Example:

```
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"    Width="100" ></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"  Width="200"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"  Width="200"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone}"  Width="100"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn   Header="Department" Binding="{Binding Departments.DepName}" Width="100"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>

        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>


    </jib:JibGrid>
```

Comment: Your query is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

JibGrid only supports nested properties up to 1 level.

You need to create a getter property (readonly property) for your nested properties.